# Are there any Free JMS Client for Delphi/Free Pascal?

Tags: delphi, jms, communication, message-queue

Does anyone knows a free (of charges) library for Delphi/Free Pascal that follows the JMS specification?

What I need is to communicate with a Message Queue Manager (which has been referenced as 'broker' where I've been reading) from my Delphi application. I've searched a while and what I've been founding is the ['Habari' JMS client](http://www.habarisoft.com/habari.html), which it is not free.

I'm using the HornetQ broker for a message queue managing, but any other approach for message queue communication between delphi applications would be considered.

I'm new to this message-oriented communication approach, so any correction will be appreaciated. Sorry for any english grammar mistakes.

Comment: Though Habari is not free, it works very well, and at EUR 49 for personal use, I don't think it is expensive.

Answer (score 0):

A "less functions" solution is to use mailslots.

Answer (score 0):

HornetQ now has a [REST client](http://www.jboss.org/hornetq/rest.html), so that should be straightforward to interface with in Delphi.

Presumably, you can also hook into .Net assemblies ? If so, you could use ActiveMQ and their [.Net Client](http://activemq.apache.org/nms/). They also have a [WebSocket client](http://activemq.apache.org/websockets.html) which you might be able to hook into.

Comment: REST does not support message push from server to client, and its throughput is quite low. Standard clients reach several thousands of messages per second on entry level hardware.